# Q-Checker Free Open Source Equivalents

Tags: catia

Just wondering if anybody has come across an open source free equivalent to Catia's Q-Checker

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no open source. But you can try to create some macros to do same job or something which can fulfill your requirements.